# Should I pass data to the component or make a request to the API in React?

Tags: reactjs, api, rest

I'm currently developing a side-project and trying to learn some general API things.

The user can access a list of projects by going to `/projects` and I'll get
all of the projects as a list. The user can also click an `Edit` button that goes to
`edit/{project_id}` and was wondering whether I should pass the project object to the component or just do a separate request to the API with the ID of the project to only get that project.
The first one is good because it's easier and also, I won't have to send all information about the `project` objects because I can't show all of them in the table (in `/project`) and this will save some data (ex. the list will show name of project and created date only). However, the second way is good because there will be less requests to the server.

My question here is, what is the preferred way?

Sidenote: I've tried searching for a question like this but didn't know how to phrase it, so this might be a duplicate.

Comment: I think this question is probably close-worthy because it's mostly a matter of opinion, but I would say you should just consider whether the edit pages will use much more data than the list pages. If it's like two fields per project on the list page and 100 on the edit page, maybe a separate API request. If it's two per project on the list page and three per project on the edit page, maybe don't bother. Of course you need to consider whether the user can get to the edit page via direct URL (where you haven't loaded all projects yet), in which case you'd need separate endpoints anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, I would advocate for the separate API request. With a list of projects, you really don't want to include everything in your "get all" API call; just enough basic stuff to populate the list. That will make your queries faster and data transfers smaller, which is especially helpful when a large number of projects come into play. However, when you "deep dive" into a single project, then you'll want everything about that single project.